# An identity involving geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},P)$ be probability space and $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N_0}$ be a geometrically distributed random variable with parameter $p\in (0,1)$ $X \backsim \text{Geo$(p)$}$. Show that $$P(X=m+n\ |X\geq m)=P(X=n), \text{ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N_0}$}. $$

I'm struggling with this question because I don't think I've entirely understood how I'm supposed to interpret distributions yet. From the definition of Geometric probability distribution we have $P(X=n)=p(1-p)^{n-1}$ which is ok but I'm not sure what expression $P(X=m+n| X\geq m)$ is meant to be equal to. My initial thought was $p(1-p)^{(n+m)-1}$  or maybe $p(1-p)^{n-1}p(1-p)^{m-1}$ but I don't see how this is supposed to fulfill the condition that $X\geq m$. I'd appreciate the help regarding this.

Comment: Do you know what that vertical bar $\mid$ means? Have you studied _conditional probabilities_ at all? The question you ask is a standard homework problem, but it would sem that you don't have the right tools to tackle the problem.

Comment: @DilipSarwate The main problem, as I've learned now, was the notation. I've had never seen the vertical bar used with distribution in that way before but I have obviously heard of conditional probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That propertie is known in probability theory as memorylessness.

The probability mass function for a geometric random variable X is $f(x)=p(1-p)^x $
The probability that X is greater than or equal to x is $ P(X ≥ x) = (1 − p)^x $ .

So the conditional probability of interest is
$P(X = m + n| X ≥ m) = \frac{P(X = m + n, X ≥ m)}{P(X ≥ m)}
                     = \frac{P(X = m + n)}{P(X ≥ m)}
                     =\frac{p(1 − p)^{(m+n)}}{(1 − p)^m}
                     = p(1 − p)^{n}$
= P(X ≥ n), $
which proves the memoryless property